# Outlook: Creating a reoccurring meeting every week but the first week of a month

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am terrible at Outlook and I have been asked to help out my BA scheduling this meeting.

She needs this meeting to occur every week except the first week of each month.  I don't see an obvious option for this within Outlook.

We are using Outlook 2007 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make 3 meetings, one for each week of the month that you would like to schedule a meeting. An alternative would be to schedule a meeting for every week, and then go through and manually cancel the "off weeks".

The disadvantage to solution #1 is that you have to manage 3 meetings (attendees, agendas, etc). The disadvantage of solution #2 is meeting spam.

Not sure of other ways.